# Change template name for Django's auth views

Tags: python, django

Ì'm using `django.contrib.auth.views.login` and `django.contrib.auth.views.logout` directly in my `urls.py` with

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

These built-in auth views are using templates in directory `registration/`.

How can I change template name for these views? Normally, I can use `...as_view(template_name='...')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views) explains this fully:

> The views have optional arguments you can use to alter the behavior of the view. For example, if you want to change the template name a view uses, you can provide the template_name argument. A way to do this is to provide keyword arguments in the URLconf, these will be passed on to the view. For example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        '^change-password/',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change',
        {'template_name': 'change-password.html'}
    )
]
```